# Create pixmap with transparent "window" in it, composite of another pixmap

Tags: c++, qt

This is an oscilloscope. I want a round, green window with a reticle over it.

If I were doing this directly, I'd fill a rect with black, draw a 0-alpha ellipse in it, and simply composite that over the other pixmap where the pixels where set to green after I had the scope trace drawn on the green pixmap.

It doesn't appear to work that way. I can fill the pixmap with transparency:

```
m_grdPixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
```

and sure enough, I get a fully transparent pixmap. I can't seem to draw anything on it, even when I construct a pen with rgba. It stubbornly stays transparent.

If I do it the other way round, that is, fill it with black:

```
m_grdPixmap.fill(QColor::fromRgb(0, 0, 0));
```

Then try to draw an ellipse on it using (what I hope is a) transparent pen, it stubbornly stays opaque:

```
painter.setPen(qRgba(0,0,0,0));
```

...or...

```
painter.setPen(qRgba(0,0,0,255));
```

I'm sure I'm missing something. This should be simple, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, good grief. It's not just wrong, it's broken.

Here's what you have to do:

1. clear the pixmap to fully transparent, a magical step with no meaning to the final image's pixel content, except if you *don't* do it, nothing works:

   `m_grdPixmap.fill(QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,0));`
2. then fill it with the actual color you want to form the "window surround", non-transparent:

   `qb = QBrush(QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,255));`
   `painter.setBrush(qb);`
   `painter.drawRect(0,0,w,h);`
3. then punch out the transparent ellipse (green here, but doesn't matter):

   `qb = QBrush(QColor::fromRgb(0,255,0,0));`
   `painter.setOpacity(1.0);`
   `painter.setBrush(qb);`
   `painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);`
   `painter.drawEllipse(center,(int)aw,(int)aw);`
4. Then composite this over the actual scene you want the "window" to reveal:

   `painter.begin(&m_scopePixmap);`
   `painter.drawPixmap(0,0,m_grdPixmap);`

...this is obscure, opaque, and near as I was able to tell, undocumented.

But there it is. And it works.

Comment: You can simply do `m_grdPixmap.fill(Qt::transparent)`, and also `qb = QBrush(Qt::black)`, `QBrush(Qt::green)` etc. :)

Comment: No, you can't. But thanks for the thought. It works exactly as I described it here -- and it doesn't work any other way. I built many test cases. This is Qt 4.7, btw. They may have fixed it in later versions, but since they broke later versions such that they won't run under the releases of OS X that I have to target, that wouldn't do me any good.

Comment: Even in Qt 4.7, `Q_ASSERT(QColor(Qt::transparent) == QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,0))` and `Q_ASSERT(QBrush(Qt::black) == QBrush(QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,255)))` and so on, and the instances of these classes (or their PIMPLs) compare binary identical. Furthermore, for a `QColor`, the `alpha=255` is the default anyway. I'm serious, check it out - add the asserts, they'll pass :) The whole purpose of the global color names was so that you wouldn't need to write code full of magical constants.

Comment: Kuba, what I needed to do was punch a transparent, eilliptical hole in an otherwise opaque rectangular pixmap. Not write something opaque in a transparent pixmap. If you have example code that is other than what I suggested above, I would be delighted to try it, and to learn how I am wrong.

Comment: All I'm saying is that anywhere you write `QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,0)` you should write `Qt::transparent`, and anywhere you write `QColor::fromRgb(0,0,0,255)` you should write `Qt::black`, and `QColor::fromRgb(0,255,0,0)` is `Qt::green`. That's all. And if you ever write `QColor::fromRgb(r,g,b,255)` you can write `QColor::fromRgb(r,g,b)` - the 255 is the default value anyway. Way less typing that way, and less magic numbers to toss around.

Comment: I see. In that case, thanks. As the primary author of several comprehensive imaging packages (DSLR image processing, animated and still special effects, general image editing), RGBA is straight-up natural to me. Explicit and clear. So I always lean that way. I can see how it would look over-specified to eyes other than mine. Appreciate the comment. Sorry I misunderstood your intent.